# Changing WooCommerce out of stock badge text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We are using the Neighborhood theme on Wordpress and Woo Commerce in order to sell one-off, unique items. Stock management works well in terms of ensuring that products sold cannot be purchased again displaying the item as out of stock instead. This in principle is fine and indeed, the display of "In stock" turning to "Out of stock" under the price on the item description works no problem and we have even found code to change that display if necessary [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117317/sell-one-unique-item-with-woocommerce). This works fine - adding the following code to the functions.php in the theme:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_html', 'change_stock_message', 10, 2);
function change_stock_message($message, $stock_status) {
    if ($stock_status == "Out of stock") {
        $message = '<p class="stock out-of-stock">Sold</p>';    
    } else {
        $message = '<p class="stock in-stock">Available</p>';           
    }
    return $message;
}
```

However, what we really want to do is change the text in the out of stock badge that appears across the image e.g. http://neighborhood.swiftideas.net/product/common-projects-achilles/.

[image]

Changing the CSS is no problem so the text font, background, size etc. is easily altered adding something like this to the custom-css:

```
.out-of-stock-badge {
    background: red;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

How to change the out-of-stock-badge text from "Out of stock" to "SOLD"?

Comment: @brasofilo code from first link already added. Second link is an example which I don't have code/snapshot for (hence the request). Have added screengrab if that helps (although I can only link the image as I haven't enough rep :( ). Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @maksbd19 suggestion I found twofiles that required editing within the woocommerce folder inside the themes folder (in this case neighborhood). These are content-product.php and single-product\product-image.php. In both cases, I change the following line from 'Out of Stock' to 'Sold' as follows:

```
...} else if (is_out_of_stock()) {
    echo '<span class="out-of-stock-badge">' . __( 'Sold', 'swiftframework' ) . '</span>';
} else if (!$product->get_price()) {...
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

March 2019 The snippet you need is in a file called wc-product-loop-outofstock-flash.php in (in my case wp-content/Themes/Avada/woocommerce )

```
<?php if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>
    <div class="fusion-out-of-stock">
        <div class="fusion-position-text">
        <?php esc_attr_e( 'Fully Booked', 'Avada' ); ?>
        </div>
     </div>
<?php
endif;
```

Check out the results [here](https://glidingclub.org.uk/product/team-training-tuesday-21st-may-2019/) but I cannot guarantee they will be around after May 2019 Fully booked items are at the bottom of the page

Comment: Can you find a way to provide "the results" in a way that won't expire? Perhaps, a screen shot that you can include as an image in your answer? (thx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the theme your are using. But I think that the following code might solve your problem-

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'woocommerce_sale_flashmessage', 10, 2);
function woocommerce_sale_flashmessage($flash){
    global $product;
    $availability = $product->get_availability();

    if ($availability['availability'] == 'Out of stock') :
        $flash = '<span class="out-of-stock-badge">'.__( 'SOLD', 'woocommerce' ).'</span>';

    endif;
    return $flash;
}
```

Add this in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Hi @maksbd19 thanks for the response. Unfortunately I can't get this to work when adding to functions.php. I understand in principle how this should work but the out-of-stock badge still reads out of stock!

Comment: what i've found out earlier that this text might come from the woocommerce template page sale-flash.php file. That might be in the location of neighborhood\woocommerce\single-product directory. If it is there then you can try changing the text there. Its really difficult trying to solve a template problem without actually having the environment.

Comment: Thanks @maksbd19, your suggestion enabled me to discover which files I needed to change which I've included in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code in your child themes header.php file

To create child theme - https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".onsale.oos").text(function () {
        return jQuery(this).text().replace("Out of stock", "SOLD"); 
    });
});
```